# компоненты ангуляр

Tags: javascript, angular, компоненты

Помогите разобраться с компонентами в анугляре.

Сделал небольшой фронтенд который содержит 4 кнопки с маршуртами.
Мне нужно что бы кнопка на основной странице изчезала после нажатия.

[image]

Основной компонент app.component.html

```
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>


<div class="center">


  <a routerLink="/menu"><button class="center1">Start</button></a>



  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

А вот app-routing module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {MenuComponent} from "./menu/menu.component";
import {SettingsComponent} from "./settings/settings.component";
import {StartPageComponent} from "./start-page/start-page.component";
import {GamePageComponent} from "./game-page/game-page.component";
import {MenuBtnComponent} from "./menu-btn/menu-btn.component";
import {PlayerChoseComponent} from "./player-chose/player-chose.component";


const routes = [

  {path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent},
  {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
  {path: 'startPage', component: StartPageComponent},
  {path: 'gamePage', component: GamePageComponent},
  {path: 'menuBtn', component: MenuBtnComponent},
  {path: 'playerChose', component: PlayerChoseComponent},
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

При нажатии на кнопку Game у меня появляються еще 3 кнопки "Settings, Back, Game". Моя проблема то что я хочу что бы при первом нажатмии на кнопку Game когда открывает другой путь самой кнопки Game не было в прилоэении

Comment: приложите в вопрос код компонента с версткой

Comment: все осталось на рабочем пк, только завтра смогу ответить

Comment: https://angular.io/start